# how to get input from user c# windows form

Tags: c#, input, type-conversion

```
int value=Convert.int32.TryPase(textbox2.text, out Number);
```

this is my code i want to get input from user using "textbox" but this code dosent work.

please tell me how to get input from user in an int value.(c# gui)

Answer (score 0):

`TryPase` first this method is called `TryParse`, then it returns `bool`. So what your code should look like:

```
int value;
if (!Convert.Int32.TryPase(textbox2.text, out value))
   //Show error
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Andrey is correct. There are some other ways to do this as well, that don't use a boolean

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.Text);
int value = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int value;
if (Int32.TryParse(textbox2.Text), value)
{
    // display error
}
```

See also:
[How to: Convert a string to an int (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx)